# IIS - Some users have seen that message: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Tags: ssl, iis, https, iis-7, iis-8

I have a problem and I can't solve it. Appears some times that mensage after install the certificate:

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

That happens if typing https://www.ihavethepower.net

Configuration:

[image]

Thanks community :)

Comment: Did you check your application logs? They should indicate the error.

Comment: Thanks alex440. I can't find logs about iis :(

Comment: Does that message appear *on every request* after you attached the SSL certificate to the site?

Comment: Hello alex440, It happens different situations and don't understand. The certificates from other sites conflict with our site, the above error message appears, etc.

Comment: Check out this document: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-windows-server-2008-iis-7.0.html. You might be missing a step. It's hard to tell from error code.

Comment: Usually it has nothing to do with the certificate. Depending on whether you use PHP or ASP.NET, there are different approaches to collect further information on such errors.